# Docker is deleting downloaded files during build when I use a VOLUME, why?

Tags: docker

I have this simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM fabric8/java-centos-openjdk8-jdk
VOLUME /tmp

RUN curl -k -Lo /tmp/oc.tar.gz "https://mirror.openshift.com/pub/openshift-v3/clients/3.6.173.0.21/linux/oc.tar.gz" && ls -l /tmp
RUN ls -l /tmp && tar zxf /tmp/oc.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin
```

It has to download a file, prints the /tmp folder contents, then ls again and extracts the downloaded file's content.

The problem is after downloading the file it is there (`&& ls -l /tmp`), but in the next `RUN ls -l /tmp` the file isn't there anymore.

```
Step 6/17 : RUN curl -k -Lo /tmp/oc.tar.gz "https://mirror.openshift.com/pub/openshift-v3/clients/3.6.173.0.21/linux/oc.tar.gz" && ls -l /tmp
 ---> Running in 5ad24909ed82
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 34.4M  100 34.4M    0     0  2489k      0  0:00:14  0:00:14 --:--:-- 5660k
total 35308
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Mar 17 11:10 hsperfdata_root
-rwx------ 1 root root      836 Mar  2 01:07 ks-script-IAlIsB
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 36145614 May 24 08:07 oc.tar.gz
-rw------- 1 root root        0 Mar  2 01:06 yum.log
Removing intermediate container 5ad24909ed82
 ---> 09e50e6d4d84
Step 7/17 : RUN ls -l /tmp && tar zxf /tmp/oc.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin
 ---> Running in 49c305788ac9
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 17 11:10 hsperfdata_root
-rwx------ 1 root root  836 Mar  2 01:07 ks-script-IAlIsB
-rw------- 1 root root    0 Mar  2 01:06 yum.log
tar (child): /tmp/oc.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

I has something to do with the `VOLUME /tmp`, without it, it works fine. What's the explanation of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the volume is defined, you won't be able to modify it. My best guess of what is happening internally during the build is that a temporary volume is setup with the temporary container used to perform the RUN step, and when the RUN step completes, the changes to the image are captured which will not include any changes to the temporary volume files. This behavior is [documented by docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume):

> Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile: If any build steps
>   change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those
>   changes will be discarded.

I've also [blogged on the topic here.](https://boxboat.com/2017/01/23/volumes-and-dockerfiles-dont-mix/)